# Texture loading problem OpenGL cant figure out why

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

Im having trouble apply a texture to an image. I just can't find the issue

The code works fine without the texture code.

Main File:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <stb_image.h>

#include "Shaders/Shader.h"


bool isWireFrame = false;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;

void framebufferCallBack(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void keyCallBack(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        isWireFrame = !isWireFrame;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    /* Initialize the library */

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "GLFW did not init!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        std::cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cerr << "Status: Using GLEW " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;


    /*
     We have to tell OpenGL the size of the rendering window so OpenGL knows how we want to display the data and coordinates with respect to the window. We can set those dimensions via the glViewport function
    */
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferCallBack);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallBack);

    Shader shader("Shaders/glsl/vert.glsl", "Shaders/glsl/frag.glsl");

    float vertices[] = {
       // positions         // tex coords
       0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,               // top right
       0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,               // bottom right
      -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,               // bottom left
      -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f                // top left 
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3

    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO, texture;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("Images/Crate.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load the texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        float timeValue = glfwGetTime();
        float greenValue = (sin(timeValue) / 2.0f) + 0.5f;
        Vector4 colour(0.0f, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


        shader.use();
        shader.setVec4("Colour", colour);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();

        if (isWireFrame == true)
        {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        }
        else if (isWireFrame == false)
        {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        }

    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shader.ID);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColour;

uniform vec4 Colour;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main()
{
    fragColour = texture(Texture, TexCoord);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.xyz, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

There are no errors.

this is my drawn object.

[[image: The output]]

this is the actual image that I want to draw:

[[image: crate image]]

The image is supposed to be a rectangle but its a triangle I don't know why that's happening maybe that bit of info can help.

Edit so I figured out that I wasn't using the right using the right colour format in the

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

but before the format parameter was `GL_RGB` instead of `GL_RGBA`

but now I have a half drawn texture:

[image: Crate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *stride* argument is wrong. Your attributes consist of 5 components (x, y, z, u, v). Therefore stride is `5 * sizeof(float)` instead of `8 * sizeof(float)`.

Additionally the size of the texture coordinates is 2 (u, v), but not 3:

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Since the image format is PNG, the texture format is `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_RGB`:

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that! thank you @Rabbid76